# How to verify domain with Facebook pixel in Angular application?

Tags: angular, facebook-pixel

As far as I read in Facebook developers API, verifying domain with Facebook pixel for Angular app, is as it follows:

1. First, you need to insert FB Pixel JS code into the page's header or footer.

```html
       !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '<PIXEL_ID>');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

2. The only change you need to make to your code is to adjust how Facebook Pixel tracks PageViews with the History State API listener provided in the pixel.

My question is that - should I insert the fb pixel script between the `head` tags in the `index.thml` file of the Angular app, or it should be loaded dynamically by JavaScript in the `app.component.ts`?
Will it work if it is loaded dynamically because it does not seem to work - the domain is not verified? Or the proper way is to add the script manually in the `index.html`?

Comment: Just put it in index.html?

Comment: Yes, that's the question. I was hoping someone's already done this in their Angular app and can confirm if this was the proper way to do it.

Comment: It is.. at least, that’s how we do it (not just with fb but also with analytics etc). We also use file replacements to only add this for production builds

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it would do no harm if I just put the fb pixel code in the `index.html` and then track the pages using History State API listener.